# Loading all JavaScripts in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to load *all* `JavaScripts` in the footer of my page which includes scripts that are only required on a specific page, which means such scripts *cannot* be included in `_Layout.cshtml`.

If my view looks something like this:

```
@model Some.Model
<p>Some paragraphs....</p>
<script> include js here </script>
```

In my view source, I want to have

```
<html>
 .....
 .....

  <footer>
    <script>
      script from _Layout
      script only required by specific page
    </script>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Is this possible in ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Razor view engine you could include a scripts section in your _Layout.cshtml:

```
    ...
    <footer>
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </footer>
</body>
```

and then inside the specific view override this section and include only the script that is needed by this view:

```
@model Some.Model
<p>Some paragraphs....</p>

@section scripts {
    <script src="script only required by specific page"></script>
}
```